# How to Copy map object from console chrome?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, console.log

I want to copy map that created in angular from console in chrome:

Map(7) {1 => {…}, 2 => {…}, 3 => {…}, 4 => {…}, 5 => {…}, …}

i can not copy this map complete!

Comment: see here https://superuser.com/questions/777213/copy-json-from-console-log-in-developer-tool-to-clipboard

Comment: it did not help me ..because i have map not json

Comment: Why do you want to copy it?

Answer (score 4):

I will assume you want to copy the map *entries*, you can use chrome's `copy` command.

```js
// create large amount of entries as an example
const entries = Array(100).fill(null).map((_, i) => [i, i]);

const map = new Map(entries);

// this would copy the map's entries to clipboard
copy(Array.from(map));
```

Comment: hi,when i use this command,it did not copy nested map!

Comment: @arezoo what do you mean it did not copy nested map? `Array.from()` creates a 2D array of entries and that gets copied to the clipboard. Do you have another `Map` as the value in your current `Map` object?

Comment: yes,i have another map in this map

Comment: @arezoo there are no `Map` literals in javascript. You could loop through the entries and check if the value is of type `Map` and convert that to an array of entries. But, that is probably of little use. You can't use `new Map(entries)`, it only creates the top level Map and not the nested ones. Again, why do you need this?

Comment: because i wanted to copy that map and paste in other place and see that and write function in robo3t(generally for my tests)